# pytest parametrize global variable as argument

Tags: pytest, parametrized-testing

I'm trying to run the same test for a series of arguments using `@pytest.mark.parametrize`. The test data must be computed dynamically, which I attempted as follows:

```
data = [("1", "2")]

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def make_data():
    global data

    data.append(("3", "4"))

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("make_data")
class Tester:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("arg0, arg1", data)
    def test_data(self, arg0, arg1):
        print(arg0, arg1)
        print(data)
        assert 0
```

I'm creating the data in the class scope fixture and then using it as the parameter set for `test_data`. I expect `test_data` to run twice, with arguments `1, 2` and `3, 4`, respectively. However, what I get is a single test with arguments `1, 2` and the following stdout:

```
1 2
[('1', '2'), ('3', '4')]
```

The value of `data` is obviously `[('1', '2'), ('3', '4')]`, which means that the class scoped fixture initialized it as I wanted. But somehow it appears that parametrization already happened before this.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve what I want? I could simply run a loop within the `test_data` method, but I feel like this defies the purpose of parametrization.

Is there a way to return `data` in the `make_data` fixture and use the fixture in `@pytest.mark.parametrize`? When using `@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg0, arg1", make_data)` I get `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`. `make_data` must be a fixture, because in the real test case it relies on other fixtures.

I am new to pytest and would be grateful for any hints. Thank you.

**EDIT**

To provide an explanation on why I'm doing what I'm doing: the way I understand, `@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg0, arg1", data)` allows parametrization with a hard-coded `data` set. What if my test data is not hard-coded? What if I need to pre-process it, like I tried in the `make_data` method? Specifically, what if I need to read it from a file or url? Let's say I have 1000 data samples for which to run the test case, how can I be expected to hard-code them?

Can I somehow use a function to generate the `data` argument in `@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg0, arg1", data)`? Something like:

```
def obtain_data():
    data = []
    # read 1000 samples
    # pre-process
    return data

@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg0, arg1", obtain_data())
```

This produces an error.

Comment: This is not a great idea to introduce global variable in unittest. You should setup probably setup you test with "setup_method function" and clean it up with "teardown_method function". When there are more complex argument in test function (such as class with state) you should use a pytest.fixture. But never a global variable

Comment: There are several issues with this code, @PicxyB points one of them. Can you provide more information on what you are trying to achieve in this test? And expand what is the source of the data (for example can there be 2 functions where one generates `("1", "2")` and the other `("3", "4")`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the [pytest-cases](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/) provides the option to define cases for the parametrization by functions, which helped a great deal. Hope this helps everyone who's looking for something similar